# Making a line (that contains "Â") an Array.

Tags: php, arrays, special-characters

I get data from webpage like ...

```
1554.65 Â 60.15 Â 4.02%
1557.30 Â 61.15 Â 4.09%
```

Now I need to get the values "1557.30","61.16" and "4.19%" from the second line.

How can make the second like an array ?

Comment: `explode` into lines and then again into columns.

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure if explode would work for Unicode characters but it's fine: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c7230ce9d2a9a6d45ea90f5b97a329c96cc6437

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// $str contains the string you mentioned.
$lines = explode('\n', $str);
$values = explode('Â', $lines[1]); // second line (0-based index).
```

`$values` would then be an array of the three elements.

Comment: $values = explode('Â', $lines[1]); dose not display anything...  But $values = explode('Â', "1557.30 Â 61.15 Â 4.09%"); works...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$txt = "1554.65 Â 60.15 Â 4.02%";
$keywords = preg_split("/Â/", $txt);
```

Out put

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '1554.65 ' (length=8)
  1 => string ' 60.15 ' (length=7)
  2 => string ' 4.02%' (length=6)
```